# How to count line breaks (not /n) in an UITextView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I would like to count how many automatic line breaks (not returns the user enters) I have in a text displayed in UITextView which is, for argument's sake, 200 pixels in width and 460 pixels in length (see attached screen shot!).

I have found this when looking for a solution:

```
stringSize = [t sizeWithFont:f constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 10000)
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

But this won't give me an int number for 'invisible' line brakes, will it? Also, I don't understand the 320, 10000 ... 320 is for the width I guess and would need to be changed to 200 in my case. But why 10.000 ??

Sorry, but I'm a beginner and this doesn't make much sense to me... 
[image]

Comment: Why do you need the amount of line breaks ? What's the higher level problem you'd like to solve ?

Comment: @DarkDust: I would like to see how much space I have left on the screen. I don't want to use scrolling - so when the page is full, I'd like to slice off the rest of the string which can't be displayed anymore and put it onto the next page. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: But then you don't about the number of lines, you care about the height of the text, or did I miss something ? And you already get the height with `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CGSizeMake` statement is to provide bounds in order to compute the size of text. It is common to constrain the width and to set a high value for the height to let enough space for the computation.

In your case, the width will be 200 and you can leave the height to 10000 as long as the text is not too long.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get an int out of CGSizeMake which will reveal how many invisible line brakes I have? Sorry if this is obvious, but I can't see how this will help me in determining invisible line brakes.

Comment: @Daniel Nicolae: Get the height of a single line using `sizeWithFont:` (without constraint it will give you the result of single line, according to the doc). Then divide the height of the constrained result with the unconstrained one.

Comment: @DarkDusk: I still don't get it, I'm afraid. I'm not so much looking for the height of a single line, but rather for the total number of lines. For instance, there are 4 lines in my example, but only one '/n' -- so there must be three invisible line breaks. How do I count them? Sorry to be a nuisance.

Comment: @n.evermind: <total_height> / <height_per_line> = <number_of_lines>